# Convert Panda DataFrame to Panel-like structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel, multi-index

I'm having a lot of trouble with a specific problem of reshaping data into the correct format.

I have data like this:

```
Date           Hour Category Col1 Col2
1/1/10  1:00   1    France   1.1  1.2
1/1/10  2:00   2    France   2.9  1.4
1/1/10  1:00   1    UK       3.8  2.3
2/1/10  1:00   1    France   1.4  1.0
2/1/10  1:00   1    UK       1.1  0.1
2/1/10  2:00   2    UK       1.2  0.4
3/1/10  1:00   1    France   0.5  0.6
```

What I need at the end is:

- each row must correspond to a unique couple (Category+Hour)
- Each row contains a list of Pd.Series (each Pd.series correspond to a date). Therefore, the length of the list corresponds to the number of days that match with the (Category+Hour)
- Each element of the list is a pd.Series object containing the other values

(So, it's related to a 3D array or a Panel, but the number of elements in the lists can change)

The output would be something like this:

```
Hour+Category    Lists
1+France         [[1/1/10 1.1 1.2] [2/1/10 1.4 1.0] [3/1/10 0.5 0.6]]
2+France         [[1/1/10 2.9 1.4]]
1+UK             [[1/1/10 3.8 2.3] [2/1/10 1.1 0.1]
2+UK             [[2/1/10 1.2 0.4]]
```

My first tries were:

```
X = X.group_by(['Hour','Category','Date']).first()
```

This creates a multi-index, which I imagine could be helpful to reshape.
I could then use

```
X.to_panel()
```

which creates a 3D panel, but where the major axis and minor axis are Hour and Category.
Else I could try

```
X.unstack(level = 2)
```

to have a 2D Array with the column being (Hour+Category) and the columns between (Day+Col1, Day+Col2) and then remove the NA values in each row and keep only the remaining values.

But I am still trying to find a better solution.
I also thought of something like this, but I can't make it work:

```
X = X.group_by(['Hour','Category']).apply(lambda x : 
[pd.Series(dict( ???)) ]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems working (you'll need to do some column renaming, etc.), but what you would like to achieve seems weird to me -- putting data in as a list/array inside a series make it harder to use later.

```
print df.groupby(['Hour', 'Category']).apply(lambda subdf : subdf[['Date','Col1','Col2']].values).reset_index()

   Hour Category                                                  0
0     1   France  [[1/1/10, 1.1, 1.2], [2/1/10, 1.4, 1.0], [3/1/...
1     1       UK           [[1/1/10, 3.8, 2.3], [2/1/10, 1.1, 0.1]]
2     2   France                               [[1/1/10, 2.9, 1.4]]
3     2       UK                               [[2/1/10, 1.2, 0.4]]
```

Comment: Indeed this works! Thank you very much.
I need it in this format to plug it into deeplearning libraries such as keras that ask for a "list of sequence" format.